# GoogleLoginService LoginFail

Tags: android

Has anyone experienced a GoogleLoginService fail when authenticating to use a google service (calendar in my case) through the AccountManager?  I obtained an authentication token using...

```
AccountManager mgr = AccountManager.get(this); 
Account[] accts = mgr.getAccountsByType("com.google"); 
Account acct = accts[0];
AccountManagerFuture<Bundle> accountManagerFuture = mgr.getAuthToken(acct, "calendar",   null, this, null, null);

Bundle authTokenBundle = null;
try {authTokenBundle = accountManagerFuture.getResult();} 
    catch (OperationCanceledException e) {e.printStackTrace();} 
    catch (AuthenticatorException e) {e.printStackTrace();} 
    catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}

authtoken = authTokenBundle.get(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN).toString();
```

After obtaining my authentication token, I created a Calendar Service and tried to authenticate it...

```
CalendarService myService = new CalendarService("UserCalendar");
myService.setAuthSubToken(authtoken);
```

When I use this on either a phone or emulator, it initially seems to work as expected... it brings up screen where google asks the user to 'allow' or 'deny' access by my app.  However, when I click allow, it says that the password of the google account is incorrect.

Now, I've tried it with multiple google accounts (both of which passwords work when I use them manually to login) and it still gives the same result.  Any ideas as per why I might be getting this?  The debug isn't extraordinarily useful... all that I get is two lines which just tell me it failed...

```
12-19 20:40:05.756: DEBUG/GoogleLoginService(245): onBind: Intent { act=android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator cmp=com.google.android.gsf/.loginservice.GoogleLoginService }
12-19 20:40:08.426: DEBUG/GoogleLoginService(245): LOGIN_FAIL
```

Has anyone else had this issue before?  I'm assuming there is something simple I'm missing but just can't think of why it wouldn't authenticate... thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The google calendar service is called "cl" not "calendar". Use the following instead:

```
mgr.getAuthToken(acct, "cl",   null, this, null, null);
```